# Excel return Price based on invoice date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, return, return-value, price

I need help with returning a product price based on its invoice date.

F.e. I have a product that has been sold on 2023-11-27 for 50 Eur. There are two different pricelists: EUR and USD. Since it has been sold for EUR, I need it to return the price list price from EUR sheet. In the EUR sheet, this product has prices ranging from 2020-01-01 to even 2024-01-01, so for example the latest price is For 2023-12-01 for 52 Eur, but the other older one was entered in 2022-01-01 and it was 49 Eur. So since the sale happened in 2023-11-27 (before 2023-12-01 price change), I need it to return the price that was available in the price list from 2022-01-01 - 49 Eur (also would be awesome if the date could be returned aswell).

I have the document attached and I did try using VLOOKUP by joining the products and dates, unfortunately I am not getting the result. I'd be really grateful!

***Main SHEET***
[image: Main SHEET]

J column has this formula at the moment:

```
=IF(I2="EUR";VLOOKUP(E2&VLOOKUP(D2;EUR!G:G;1;TRUE);EUR!A:J;7;0);VLOOKUP(E2&VLOOKUP(D2;USD!G:G;1;TRUE);USD!A:J;7;0))
```

*The products I print screened don't matter here at the moment (it's a huge list)*

***EUR sheet***
[image: EUR sheet]

***USD Sheet***
[image: USD sheet]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=For%20larger%20code%20snippets%2C%20you,actual%20code%20and%20formatting%20it.)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working.

I use a filter formula to get all dates that match inventory part no and is less than purchase date. Then I sort the filtered dates descending and grab the first one with sequence.
This gives me the date which is the key to then use a sumproduct formula to get the price.
This much smaller example worked fine.

[image]

Notice that I added a march value last to make sure it works even with unsorted data.

The formula to get the date is:

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER(EUR!J:J,(EUR!D:D=E2)*(EUR!J:J<D2),""),,-1),SEQUENCE(1,1,1,1))
```

Then to get the price:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((EUR!J:J=<Date from previous formula>)*(EUR!D:D=E2)*EUR!G:G)
```